# Why did my 150+ reputation account at Movies & TV SE get suspended?

Tags: support, account-suspension

Day before yesterday, I posted two questions ([1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75055/how-is-a-blind-character-working-at-film-developer-lab), [2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75045/why-do-some-scenes-have-bad-video-audio)) on Movies & TV Stack Exchange. One of my two questions got listed in Hot Network Questions also. I was so happy, I even shared in my FB, but today when I logged in, it showed I am **suspended**.

My profile pic on these two questions became transparent like this:

[image]

My account got suspended without any kind of notification; this includes spam folder in my email.

I already achieved 150+ reputation.

Comment: I'd guess you would have recieved some kind of notification saying that it happened and why it happened.

Comment: If I receive some kind of notification like you said then I wouldn't be post question here for asking the suspension reason. I clearly didn't receive any kind of notification, direct suspension.

Comment: I'm saying it may be coming. They may send out the messages in batches all at once like they do some other things. I phrased that first comment poorly in retrospect.

Comment: A moderator *must* send a message when suspending; there is no option to suspend someone without sending a message. You should get a notification for this message on the site and an email. In your case, it looks like the account didn't get suspended but *deleted*; this is typically done only for spam or accounts otherwise used only for blatant abuse. It may have been a mistake; we'll have to wait for one of the Movie mods to clarify things.

Comment: Thank You for responding, I already checked my email inbox, there is no messages about suspension including spam folder also.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Actually, their account is still there. The questions appear to have been dissociated from it, though.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Disassociation results in the posts being attributed to "anon", not to "userXXX". In this case, it appears the questions were posted from OP's other account. I guess the mod thought there was foul play, deleted one account and suspended the other.

Comment: Why were you creating multiple accounts then?

Comment: ummm.... obviously you misused sockpuppet account. Not sure what you try to get here.

Comment: I really don't know why someone is trying to close this as "site-specific". How do you expect someone with a deleted and a suspended account to ask on a site meta, anyway?

Answer (score 25):

On Movies & TV we have had a pattern over the last few months of a user creating multiple accounts, of the order of one a day to ask a few questions about a single movie.

There was some evidence that these accounts were also involved in sockpuppet voting for each other, and that attempts were made to use proxy servers to appear to come from different IP addresses.

Most of the accounts ask a small number of questions about a single movie, then go silent.  In most cases these accounts created use no more than the auto suggested username, don't include an email address, and do not respond to moderator messages or other attempts to ask them to stop this behavior.

The moderators of the site have taken to deleting these accounts as they appear.  Your account user52765 was flagged as likely to be one of these accounts and was deleted.  As a result of this, the account you are posting with here was automatically banned by the system - I am presuming because of a shared IP address (but this is a guess on my part).

I would also add, that since the account that posted here doesn't actually have a registered email address, how would you expect an email to be sent to you about the suspension?